# How to replace multiple character in string of data frame in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have such a data frame:

```
#v1   v2    v3    v4   v5
 a    b     b     c    1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 4 4 ...
....
```

As you see, the `v5` column contains `word id`. And I have a list of `word id` to remove:

```
toRve = ['1','3','5'.....]
```

And I write a `for loop` to remove the `word id` in list:

```
for i in toRve:
    df[v5] = df[v5].str.replace("{0} ".format(i), "")
```

But I got this result:

```
 #v1   v2    v3    v4   v5
  a    b     b     c    222444444 ...
....
```

As the `22 23`has been regarded `2`+`2`+`23` so it has been changed to `223`. Do you have any good idea to solve this problem? Thank you in advance!

Why all the space has gone? Could you help me? Thank you in advance!

Comment: @jezrael Thanks for reply. But it will cause lots of redundant spaces and `22` will change to `2` either. I want exactly `i` (2) to be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `apply` method to run a function for every element:

```
import pandas as pd

s = pd.Series([
        "1 1 2 2 3 3 4 4 5 5 6 6 6",
        "3 4 2 1 2 3 4 4 5 5 4 34 2"
    ])

todel = set(["1", "3", "5"])
s.apply(lambda x:" ".join(v for v in x.strip().split() if v not in todel))
```

the output:

```
0       2 2 4 4 6 6 6
1    4 2 2 4 4 4 34 2
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems very promising! But how to make the space before the first character removed? It will affect the training of my model. Thanks a lot.